# Having trouble with arrays

Tags: c++

I'm 100% sure my code is incorrectly determining the size of the array 
When I put in hello as the input and set strArray[5] it works correctly. But the problem is I don't know how big the size of the input will be so I just put 80 (since that's the max it could be)

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

main()
{
string str1;
char strArray[80];


cout << "Enter string: ";
getline(cin, str1);

transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), ::tolower);
str1.erase(remove(str1.begin(),str1.end(),' '),str1.end());

for(int i = 0;i < str1.length(); i++)
{
        if(str1[i] == ',' || str1[i] == '.')
        {
            str1.erase(i,1);
        }
}

for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++)
{
        strArray[i] = str1[i];
}

char tempChar;

for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(strArray)/sizeof(*strArray))-1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (sizeof(strArray)/sizeof(*strArray)-1); j++)
    {
        if(strArray[j+1] < strArray[j])
        {
            tempChar = strArray[j];
            strArray[j] = strArray[j+1];
            strArray[j+1] = tempChar;
        }
    }
}

cout << strArray << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use string,not char table

Comment: What are you trying to do in that loop?

Comment: Are you just trying to find the length of the string after removing commas and periods?

Comment: Isn't the size of the input still str1.length()? Well, after the transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make strArray a string.  Or, if you must use a `char` array, you should dynamically allocate the char array with `char *strArray = new char[str1.length()]`.  In this case, don't forget to `delete [] strArray;` when done.